# Javascript data-* attributes calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

The problem is that a selection of elements sumirovalis each other .. The value of the element specified in the "data-price". My code is not valid and is not handled properly, it is desirable to change the amount at any depression.
Thank you for any assistance conditional

html

```
<input name="tarifs" id="tarifs2" type="radio" data-price="590" value="Abs">
<input name="tarifs" id="tarifs1" type="radio" data-price="540" value="Abs"><br/>
<input name="tv[]" id="tv3" type="checkbox" data-price="150" value="Abs">
<input name="tv[]" id="tv2" type="checkbox" data-price="100" value="Abs"><br/>
<input name="tv2[]" id="tv4" type="checkbox" data-price="250" value="Abs">
<input name="tv2[]" id="tv5" type="checkbox" data-price="350" value="Abs"><br/>
Sum: <span id="checkout-sum"></span></div>
```

JS

```
$("input[name=tarifs]").keyup(function() {
    var sum1 = $("input[name=tarifs]").data("price");
    var sum2 = $("input[name=tv[]]").data("price");
    var sum3 = $("input[name=tv2[]]").data("price");

    var total = sum1 + sum2 + sum3;

    $("#checkout-sum").val(total);
});
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4Chv2/)

Comment: Change `.keyup(` to `.change(` and have a look in the console. After this have a look at [Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: What exactly do you want as the output/result? Sum of all checked values? Or simply sum of all checkboxes ?

Comment: The sum of all the chosen values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will use `change` event and only look for checked inputs. This will work when any of the radios or checkboxes shown changes

```
$inputs=$('#tarifs1,#tarifs2,#tv2,,#tv3,#tv4,#tv5').change(function(){
    var total=0;
    $inputs.filter(':checked').each(function(){
        total+= $(this).data('price');
     });
    $("#checkout-sum").text(total);
})
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QaMrT/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you, your version works =) http://jsfiddle.net/4Chv2/5/. Just one question, you can make the place a job id (# tarifs1), job name (name = "tarifs")? because will probably be a lot of id.

Comment: Use a single class on all the ones you want included. Then only need to use that class for selector

Comment: Or perhaps easier `$(".parentWrpper :input')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
Your missing quotes in jQuery selector: $("input[name=**'tv[]'**]

```
$("input[name=tarifs],[name='tv[]'],[name='tv2[]']").change(function() {
    var sum1 = $("input[name=tarifs]:checked").data("price"); 
    var sum2 = $("input[name='tv[]']:checked").data("price");    
    var sum3 = $("input[name='tv2[]']:checked").data("price");  
    var total = sum1 + sum2 + sum3;
  $("#checkout-sum").html(total);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4Chv2/4/)**

another way:

```
$input = $("input[name=tarifs],[name='tv[]'],[name='tv2[]']");

$input.change(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $input.filter(':checked').each(function(){
       sum = sum + $(this).data("price");
    });
  $("#checkout-sum").html(sum);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4Chv2/9/)**

Comment: Is not working properly =(. If you choose to $tarifs1 that displays 590. When data-price = "540".
+ You can do that would change with the choice, all data were recalculated?

Comment: Option number 2 is fully fit. Thank you very much =)

Comment: last version assumes no other `input` that might be checked anywhere else in page..dangerous

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:-

```
$("input").change(function() {

    var sum1 = $("input[name='tarifs']:checked").data("price"),
    sum2 = 0,
    sum3= 0;

    $.each($("input[name='tv[]']:checked"), function(index,item) {
      sum2 += $(item).data('price');
   });

      $.each($("input[name='tv2[]']:checked"), function(index,item) {
       sum3 += $(item).data('price');
    });

    var total = +sum1 + sum2 + sum3;

    $("#checkout-sum").html(total);
});
```